# PHP how can i hide part of url

Tags: php

I'm working on a project and need to hide part of a url on the output result of my php file, how can i do that?

the piece of code

```
    if (!$foundPlaylist){
                $playList=array(                
['publishedAt'], 
                            'thumbId'     => $entry[$i]['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'],
                            'videosCount' => $videoCount,
                            'videos'      => getVideos($entry[$i]['snippet']['resourceId']['videoId']) 
                        );
                array_push($MainFeed,$playList);    
            }
```

The result

```
{ "feed":[{"thumbId":"https://i.ytimg.com/vi/SEchOz24pd8/mqdefault.jpg","videosCount":20,"videoid":"SEchOz24pd8",}],"0":
```

I need to hide `https://i.ytimg.com/vi/` and `/mqdefault.jpg` from thumbId.

Comment: I hope my answer helps out. It is more generic than counting characters and using `substr()` / `mb_substr()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use

```
substr($entry[$i]['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'], 23, 11);
```

to select only the part of the URL between position 23 and (23+11) = 34

This, of course, only works if you know the string length is going to be exactly the same for all users. If you know the string length will differ, Anthony's answer might help you out.

Comment: But the string length might differ for different users. Needs to be more generic. Less specific.

Comment: When i apply to 'echo '{ "feed":'.json_encode($MainFeed).' }';' it doesn't work.

Comment: In my tests, `json_encode` works fine. Perhaps there's a problem elsewhere in the `$MainFeed` array?

Answer (score 0):

I find this most readable:

```
$path = parse_url(
    $entry[$i]['snippet']['thumbnails']['medium']['url'],
    PHP_URL_PATH
);
list($user, $code, $image) = explode('/', $path);

echo $code;
```